# jQuery .change() not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just working on some small pages to be elements of a much larger project and am completely confused at my current problem here is my code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
  .questionBlock { font-size: x-large; color: red }
</STYLE>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
alert("sdsd")
$("input[@name='questionType']").change(function(){
    alert("dfdfdf");
    var selected = $("form input:radio:checked").val();
    alert(selected);
})
});

</script>

<form action="">
<input type="radio" name="questionType" value="closed" /> Closed Endeded<br />
<input type="radio" name="questionType" value="matrix" /> Matrix Question<br />
<input type="radio" name="questionType" value="open" /> Open Ended
</form>

<div class="questionBlock" id="closed">lol</div>
<div class="questionBlock" id="open">rol</div>
<div class="questionBlock" id="matrix">bol</div>
```

But the change event never fires, regardless of browser, I've tried using bind as well but it's driving me up the wall!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery [attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) don't need @ prefix (like XPath). Change your code like this:

```
$("input[name='questionType']").change(function(){
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/yfQ9A/) is a working version.

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove the @ [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hea6K/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $('input[name="questionType"]').change(function(){
        alert("dfdfdf");
        var selected = $("form input:radio:checked").val();
        alert(selected);
    })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery does not use "@" in Xpath-style attr selectors anymore. This being the case, your selector does not match anything.